# Filtered options for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, html-select

I'm really stuck in a issue.

I've a RoR application in which I'd like to populate `select_tag` with filtered options lets say `Physicians`. Here is my `select_tag` in view:

```
<%= select_tag "phyID",options_from_collection_for_select(@physicians,'id','fullNamePhy'),:include_blank => true %>
```

In controller I have

```
@physicians=User.find_by_userType('Physician')
```

but I'm getting error:

```
undefined method `map' for #<User:0x3b09820>
```

It seems like I have to use `User.all` instead of `User.find`. Please let me know any work around. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@physicians = User.where(userType: 'Physician')
```

You're getting error because `options_from_collection_for_select` expects object that behaves like `Array`, for example `ActiveRecord::Relation` instance. But `find_by_*` dynamic finder returns object representing singular record, `User` instance in this case.

BTW, column names in Rails are by convention named with underscore instead of camel case , like `user_type`.

Comment: Thanks @Marek . it worked. will mark as an answer in 10  mins :)

Comment: Yes, as i am from .Net background it happens too often with me  to use camel cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic `find_all_by` finder

```
@physicians = User.find_all_by_userType('Physician')
```

`find_by_column_names` returns single record. Where as `select_tag` expects collection/array of record

Comment: Warning: [Deprecated in Rails 4](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations).